# What is the full ancestry of Janaka?

Tags: ramayana, ancestry

In the Bala Kanda of the Ramayana, during the wedding of Rama and Sita, both families share their respective family trees.  Vashishta [presents](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/bala/sarga70/bala_70_frame.htm) a long genealogy for Rama's family, the Ikshvaku dynasty, going all the way back to the gods including Surya, Brahma, and ultimately Vishnu.  Then Sita's father Janaka [presents](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/bala/sarga71/bala_71_frame.htm) his ancestry as follows:

> Once there was an emperor Nimi, who was renowned in the triad of worlds by his own accomplishments, and who was uniquely seraphic-souled and a best one among all stalwart emperors.  And his son was named as Mithi, and Janaka was Mithi's son, the first one to be designated as Janaka.  And even from that Janaka it is Udaavasu who took birth. From Udaavasu it is noble souled Nandivardhana took birth, and Nandivardhana's son is named as Suketu, by his name.  From Suketu the highly powerful and virtue-souled Devaraata is born, and from that kingly sage Devaraata, it is Brihadratha who took birth, thus we have heard.  From Brihadratha it is the highly braving, courageous and valiant Mahaaviira has come, and the bold and truth-valiant Sudhriti from Mahaaviira.  Form Sudhriti, the right-minded and highly generous Dhristaketu took birth, and from the kingly sage Dhristaketu it is highly renowned Haryashva is the son.  Haryashva's son is Maru, and Maru's, son is Pratiindhaka, and the son of Pratiindhaka's is noble-souled king Kiirtiratha.  The son of Kiirtiratha is remembered as Devamiidha, and the son of Devamiidha is Vibudha, and Vibudha's son is Mahiidraka. Mahiidraka's son is the great mighty king Kiirtiraata, and the son born to sagely king Kiirtiraata is Mahaaroma.  From Mahaaroma it is the virtue-souled Swarnaroma, and from kingly sage Swarnaroma it is Hrasvaroma.  Two sons are born to that knower of virtue and noble souled Hrasvaroma, I am the elder, and my younger brother is this brave Kushadhvaja.

So Janaka's lineage is presented up to "an emperor Nimi".  But my question is, what is Janaka's ancestry beyond Nimi?  Are there any scriptures that trace the ancestry of Janaka all the way back, just as Vashishta did for Rama?  Was Janaka of the solar dynasty (Suryavansha) or some other dynasty?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Janaka's ancestry beyond Nimi is same as Rama's. Because Nimi was the brother of Vikuksi on whose lineage Rama appeared. So Janaka was also of solar dynasty.

Iksvaku had one hundred sons, among which 3 were prominent: Vikuksi, Nimi and Dandaka.

> *kṣuvatas tu manor jajñe ikṣvākur ghrāṇataḥ sutaḥ*
>   *tasya putra-śata-jyeṣṭhā vikukṣi-nimi-daṇḍakāḥ* [[SB - 9.6.4](http://vedabase.com/en/sb/9/6/4)]
>
> **Meaning**
>   While sneezing, from the nostril of Manu, Iksvaku was born. Iksvaku had hundred sons among which the eldest were Vikuksi, Nimi and Dandaka.