Was king Nimi the father of Rama?
Is king Nimi the same figure as Dasharatha, king of Kosala, and the father of Rama?  The wiki says this:

In several traditions, a righteous and edifying Videhan King Nimi or
Nemi is mentioned, who travels to heaven and hell in a celestial
chariot.

Of Dasharatha it says:

He was originally named Nemi, but he acquired the moniker Dasharatha
('ten chariots') as his chariot could move in all ten directions, fly,
and return to earth, and he could fight with ease in all of these
directions.


In a battle between the devas and the asuras, Dasharatha rode to
Devaloka, accompanied by Kaikeyi, to help Indra fight against the
asuras.

Buddhist discourse tell of a king Nimi too:

Then Sakka, lord of gods, addressed his charioteer Mātali, ‘Come, dear
Mātali, harness the chariot with a thousand thoroughbreds. Then go to
King Nimi and say, “Great king, this chariot has been sent for you by
Sakka, lord of gods. Mount the heavenly chariot, great king! Do not
waver.”’


related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10852/16165

related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/460/16165

if the translation is correct, Maghadeva Sutta says that Indra, or Magha, is the father of king Nimi.  I don't think this can be true, unless Indra is Ikshvaku (supposedly translated Okkākā in Pali).  I am saying that Ikshvaku is Nimi's father, although I am uncertain of all of this
