Which Janaka does Śūka Goswami see?
There were supposedly many Janakas starting with king Mithi, son of king Nimi.  The Devi Bhagavatam tells of Śūkadeva Goswami visiting the Janaka of Videha kingdom.  Does it give the name of this Janaka of Mithila?  Whomever it is, it must be a contemporary of king Parikshit of Kuru kingdom.  The encounter between Śūkadeva and Janaka can be found in canto 1 chapters 16-19 of Srimad Devi Bhagavatam.

related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/453/what-is-the-full-ancestry-of-janaka/460#460

At least not the Janakas mentioned in Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa. In other words not Sītā’s foster father or any of his ancestors, as they existed much before Kṛṣṇa Dvaipāyana Vyāsa himself

i don't even understand the answer so what does it matter?

"suka died even before the birth of Bhishma"

"Thus all Purāna are dependent on Mahabharata."

is this name really pronounced shūka, or sūkha (like not duhkha)?
